# SQL Server Compact connection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-express

I created a SQL Server Compact database file `aa.sdf` and I am trying to connect it to my VB.NET code. But it can not connect to it

```
Dim MyConnexion As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=C:\Users\W8\Documents\aa.sdf;" & "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=toto")
Dim Requete As String = "Insert into toto(ID, sumAp) values (11,22)"
Dim Commande As New SqlCommand(Requete, MyConnexion)

MyConnexion.Open()
```

I get this message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

I am a beginner at SQL...

My table is `toto`:

```
ID    sumAp
1     11
2     21
```

Thank you

Comment: You appear to be using a `SqlConnection`, which would normally connect to a server, rather than a `SqlCeConnection` which would normally be used to connect the a Compact Edition database?

Comment: Great! It workds, I needed to add Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe and

Comment: You may need to import its namespace, i.e. have `Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe` instead of `Imports System.Data.SqlServer` at the top of your source file

Comment: Yes I edited my first message, I found it. Thanks again

Comment: Just converted to a better worded answer so that you can flag your question as answered...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect to Compact Edition databases, you need to instead use `SqlCeConnection` (in the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace, if you haven't already imported it), so instead, I'd expect your code to look a little like:

```
Using con As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\Users\W8\Documents\aa.sdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=toto")
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlCeCommand("Insert into toto(ID, sumAp) values (11,22)", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```